# OneToMany relationship with cacade.ALL doesn't persist last added element

Tags: java, hibernate

The code goes as follows

1. Create and persist the vacancy
2. Loop over a list of partners. For each partner:
   i. Create and persist the partner (if it doesn't exist yet)
   ii. Link the partner to the vacancy
3. Persist the vacancy again, this time with the partner-vacancy links in a Set

All links are persisted, except for the last one.
The earlier links are stored the on step 2.i, when we try to fetch a partner from the database. At that point, it executes the insert statement of the previously created link.

Any ideas on why this last link is not persisted?

```
@Entity
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Vacancy {
    @Id
    private Long id

    @NaturalId
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long vacancyId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vacancyemphasized text", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PartnerVacancy> partnerVacancies;

    void addPartnerVacancy(PartnerVacancy partnerVacancy) {
        if (partnerVacancies == null) {
            partnerVacancies = new HashSet<>();
        }
        partnerVacancies.add(partnerVacancy);
    }

    void removePartnerVacancy(PartnerVacancy partnerVacancy) {
        if (partnerVacancies == null) {
            return;
        }
        partnerVacancies.remove(partnerVacancy);
    }

    public void linkPartner(Partner partner) {
        PartnerVacancy partnerVacancy = new PartnerVacancy()
                .setPartner(partner)
                .setVacancy(this);
        addPartnerVacancy(partnerVacancy );
        partner.addPartnerVacancy(partnerVacancy );
    }

    public void unlinkPartner(Partner partner) {
        PartnerVacancy partnerVacancy = new PartnerVacancy()
                .setPartner(partner)
                .setVacancy(this);
        removePartnerVacancy(partnerVacancy );
        partner.removePartnerVacancy(partnerVacancy );
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Partner {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String partnerUuid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "partner", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PartnerVacancy> partnerVacancies;

    void addPartnerVacancy(PartnerVacancy partnerVacancy) {
        if (partnerVacancies == null) {
            partnerVacancies = new HashSet<>();
        }

        partnerVacancies.add(partnerVacancy);
    }

    public void removePartnerVacancy(PartnerVacancy partnerVacancy) {
        if (partnerVacancies == null) {
            return;
        }

        partnerVacancies.remove(partnerVacancy);
    }

    public void linkVacancy(Vacancy vacancy) {
        PartnerVacancy partnerVacancy = new PartnerVacancy()
                .setPartner(this)
                .setVacancy(vacancy);
        addPartnerVacancy(partnerVacancy);
        vacancy.addPartnerVacancy(partnerVacancy);
    }

    public void unlinkVacancy(Vacancy vacancy) {
        PartnerVacancy partnerVacancy = new PartnerVacancy()
                .setPartner(this)
                .setVacancy(vacancy);
        removePartnerVacancy(partnerVacancy);
        vacancy.removePPartnerVacancy(partnerVacancy);
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PartnerVacancyId.class)
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class PartnerVacancy{
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Parttner partner;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Vacancy vacancy;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationDate;
}
```